# Why isn't the Enterprise Library MsmqTraceListener writing messages to the queue I created?

Tags: .net, msmq, enterprise-library

I created a queue in MSMQ, granted permissions, added the config for the MsmqTraceListener and BinaryLogFormatter and necessary categories.  When I switch to the RollingFlatFileTraceListener and TextFormatter, everything is fine.  There appear to be no exceptions thrown and no Event Log messages written.  My goal is to setup MsmqDistributor.exe on a central server to collect logging from multiple machines and stuff them in the database using a database listener on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my own answer.  The original queue I created was transactional (I've been creating transactional queues for WCF lately).  When I created a non-transactional queue, the EntLib logger was much happier.